# .htaccess % rewrite rule crash server

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to use the `urlencode()` function which will make urls contain '%' sign.

My current rewrite does not allow these characters so i need to update it and what ive tried crashes the whole server.

Sample URL/A tag: `<a href="/edit-portfolio/MQ%3D%3D">Test Link</a>`

Old `.htaccess` (Working great untill i needed `urlencode()`)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]
```

New `.htaccess` (Crashes site)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-%]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-%]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$ [NC,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes site"? Do you get a 404 error or something you didn't expect?

Comment: This is what i get when i use the new access file: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: You can't match against encoded  `=` in pattern of a RewriteRule.  To match against `%3D` you need to include a `=` to your regex character class ie : `[..........=]`

Comment: @wiktorstribiżew The question is about how to match url decoded characters in RewriteRule while the linked question is about how to match hypens with regex and it's totally different.

Comment: @wiktorstribiżew I understand that but RewriteEngine is a bit different . `-` isn't the actual reason of server crash .OP ' s existing regex pattern is almost good. But the question you put as duplicate doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wiktorstribiżew I have already mentioned the reason in a previous comment to the question. The accepted answer worked because it uses a catch - all pattern instead of hard coded string or character - class and correctly matches all url - decoded characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take care of `-` in a character class because it may define a range. Just to be sure escape it all the time:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-%]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-%]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$ [NC,L]
                         ^                  ^
```

*`[_-%]` this range isn't valid at all*

or move it to the end of character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_%-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_%-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$ [NC,L]
```

By the way all could be shortened to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&c=$2 [NC,L]
                                                   ^ You missed this one
```

Comment: Thats pretty neat i were not at all aware of this.

I accepted your answer, thanks alot im relly impressed with the last short one i still cant figure out how that works but i will dive into it :)